# laravel "saved search" feature for real estate list application

Tags: laravel, saved-searches

I am developing an application to list real estate properties.
I would like to add a "saved search" feature similar to eBay or Linkedin.
A user can search for a property with the following attributes:

1. Location
2. Bed Rooms
3. Property type
4. min price  max price

He can then save this search and receive every day by email or SMS the newly published ads that match his search. Do you have any feedback on how to implement this feature? The search feature is working but how to save a search and send an email when newly published ads that match his search.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to save the search parameters, in a table for example.

Then you have several options on how you could implement the feature:

- Event (when ad is created) https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/events#main-content.
- Job (when ad is created) https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#creating-jobs
- Task Scheduling (every day, week, etc.) https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scheduling#main-content
- Probably other ways that I can't think of right now

Then you will have to write the code to check if the created ads match the search parameter or not and send the notification when they do.